# How to get all selected indices in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, indices

I have a datagrid with the option SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended.

With that I can select various row.

[image]

I would like to know the indices of the selected rows.
I am aware that I can get dtg_ExecutionTimes_PpDescriptions.SelectedItems but I am not able to retrieve the indices from that list.
For example in the picture it is 1 and 3 (or 0 and 2)

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways, if you don't have reference duplicates in your items source (what is usually the case), then you can iterate through the items and get the indexes:

```
var selIndexes = new List<int>();
foreach (var selItem in dtg_ExecutionTimes_PpDescriptions.SelectedItems)
{
    selIndexes.Add(dtg_ExecutionTimes_PpDescriptions.Items.IndexOf(selItem));
}
```

Comment: It says that iList hasn't got the select member. Are you sure that this is WPF?

Comment: OK, my bad. I haven't kept an eye on return type of `SelectedItems`. I have updated an answer.

Comment: That works like a charm. Really really much appreciated! Thanks